# How to find the list of relevant IEEE journals to publish a paper in?

Tags: publications, journals, ieee, publishability

If one has research findings in a topic *X*, and wishes to publish it in one of the many IEEE journals, which is the best way to list the journals that includes *X* within its scope?

Note that the solution to *X* might use one or more of frameworks of [A, B ..], where 'A' can covered in the scope of journal *J1* and 'B' can be within the scope of journal *J2* and so on.

The obvious method might be checking up on the keywords in IEEEXplore and look for journals corresponding to previously published papers that come up. But is there any other way?

Comment: I would suggest that, if you are broadly familiar with the literature that covers your research topic (and a bit beyond as well), it should be pretty obvious which journals, IEEE and beyond, accept articles in and around the topic. My personal experience was more questioning which journal would be _best_ for a given paper (how exciting, novel, whatnot). I never wondered _which_ journals might publish it.

Comment: Look in the bibliography of your paper. Which IEEE journal do you cite the most?

Comment: @JeffE That's a pretty straight forward way to look at it. That is how I've been doing till now. (Thanks, but the way)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IEEE.org currently has a [Publication Recommender](http://publication-recommender.ieee.org/home) tool where you input the keywords, key phrases, title, abstract etc. of your article, or the actual document of the article (in pdf, doc, docx or tex format). You can narrow the search to periodicals and/or conferences, or the date you want to publish before. I tried it with the two articles I've actually finished, and received a few good recommendations with high relevance scores for both.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the *simplest* and *quickest* (but not necessarily the most *optimal*) solution would be to **rank** those frameworks [A, B, ...] by your favorite *criteria* (i.e., importance, fit to my research career goals/interests, fit to my department's research interests, etc.) and then perform **bibliometric search** within the IEEE journals scope, using one or more of your top-ranked frameworks as keywords. The resulting list of journals would be pretty **relevant** to your paper as well as to your most important criteria.